# select2 validation - Select a minimum of one value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

I am using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugins.

HTML for select2:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="select2Region"><h3>Set Location</h3></label><br />
<input type="hidden" id="select2Region" style="width:40%" required/>
</div>
```

select2 Initiation:

```
        $('#select2Region').select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            data: $.parseJSON(selectRegion),
            placeholder: "Enter your City here",
            allowClear: true

        });
```

Data is populating perfectly fine. Now, i want users to select a value.

As is mentioned [in Github](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/215), i tried this:

> Try adding ignore: '', in the line directly above rules:. An empty string did the job for me since ignore: null, wasn't working.

and this as well:

```
$('.select2').select2().change(function(){
   $(this).valid();
});
```

But they both are not working for me. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: i dnt even know how to tell this.wasted an hour.comes out i missed the name attribute!!! Gosh, i feel embarrassed

Comment: Please show your jQuery Validate code in the question and then post your solution below as an answer.  Otherwise, feel free to flag for deletion.

Comment: @Sparky have updated the answer. Is that all right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Validate Code

```
        $("#myForm").validate({
          ignore: '',
          messages: {
            select2Start: {
              required: "Please select your starting point.",
            }
          }
        });
```

n my HTML code goes like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select2Region"><h3>Set Location</h3></label><br />
  <input type="hidden" id="select2Region" name="select2Region" style="width:40%" required/>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer seems to have nothing to do with your comment:  _"i missed the name attribute!"_ ~ One of the main purposes of this site is as a high quality repository of questions/answers that make enough sense to future readers that it may help them with a similar problem.  Based on what you've shown in your question/answer/comments, I still have no idea what you did wrong or why/how this answer fixes it.

Comment: hey man thanks a lot! i am banned from asking a question! thats just great

Comment: I don't have the power to ban anyone... that's likely done automatically based on your posting history, votes, etc.  Feel free to take your complaints over to [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to discuss with the moderators.